# IntelliJ CSS autocomplete / Emmet?

Tags: css, intellij-idea

I'm having some issues with **IntelliJ 13** and autocompletion when editing CSS. Normally to set `margin:` I used to type: `mar` <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Now, with the new version, I get `max-resolution` instead:

[image: Screenshot]

I had originally assumed it was due to the new [Emmet](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/emmet.html) functionality, but I've already switched it off and the issue still occurs:

[image: Emmet Settings]

Anybody experiencing anything similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a preselection bug which has been fixed in IDEA 13.1, please try its RC from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP. There, the live template must be preselected if its exact key is entered in the editor.

If you don't want to see these live templates at all, you can go to Settings | Live Templates and disable the whole Zen CSS group.

Comment: I see, then I was wrong and that's another issue. The easiest way to get rid of those variants is to go to Settings | Live Templates and disable the whole Zen CSS group

Answer (score 2):

Type: `m` <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead, you may find the results to your liking.

Comment: I appreciate that I could *work differently*, but I would really like the autocomplete to just work from left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helps me something opposite.

I checked the Live Templates > Zen CSS and after this, I can use snippets like bdrs(border-radius) etc from Emmet.